# iOS banner notification

Tags: ios, notifications, banner

I noticed recently a banner notification on my iPhone I haven't seen before. I can't find description of these banners, for example [here](http://heresthethingblog.com/2014/01/22/ios-7-tip-whats-difference-alert/). Here they are:

[image: banner 1]

[image: banner 2]

First of them appears when an app goes in background. Tap on the banner shows the app again.
The second appears when I create a Hotspot and tap on it shows Hotspot settings.

So, my questions are:

1. What are these banners?
2. Why they have different colors?
3. How can I create the same banner in my own app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue banner is there if the "personal hotspot" feature is turned on, and some other device is using the shared internet connection.

The red banner is shown for example if an app that is not currently in the foreground is accessing the microphone.

Both banners are provided by the operating system and are not customizable by app developers. These banners can sometimes make problems when your app is not prepared to re-layout its views as a result of this banner appearing or disappearing. Therefore, you can simulate this banner in the iOS-simulator by pressing CMD-Y (XCode6 iOS Simulator => Hardware => Toggle In-Call Status Bar).

Furthermore, these banners are not really "notifications", they are more like status hints that provide a visual cue to the user that the phone is in an exceptional state (red=microphone access, green=a phone call is in progress, blue=personal hotspot is in use.)

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Very interesting answer! :) Is there any description in the official documentation?

Comment: @LembergSun: maybe, but I haven't found it yet. I just learned this stuff from experience.

Comment: How to detect that banner is appearing or not?